# Integral equations that can be solved elementary

Tags: integral-equations

> Solve the following integral equations:
>   $$
> \int_0^xu(y)\, dy=\frac{1}{3}xu(x) \tag 1 \label 1
> $$
>   and
>   $$
> \int_0^xe^{-x}u(y)\, dy=e^{-x}+x-1. \tag 2 \label 2
> $$

Concerning $\eqref 1$, I read that it can be solved by differentiation. Differentiation on both sides gives
$$
u(x)=\frac{1}{3}(u(x)+xu'(x))\Leftrightarrow u'(x)=\frac{2}{x}u(x)
$$
and then by separation of this ODE the solution is $u(x)=Cx^2$.

How can I solve $\eqref 2$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part

Comment: Ok, thanks, I got it. I edit it!

Comment: For part 2 first take $e^{-x}$ out of the integral

Comment: Solve for *what*?

Comment: u is searched here.

Comment: Try solving this one: $$\int e^{-f(x)}dx=f(x).$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

$$\int_0^xe^{-x}u(y)\, dy=e^{-x}+x-1$$ So $$  e^{-x}\int_0^xu(y)\, dy=e^{-x}+x-1$$ and therefore, $$ \ \int_0^xu(y)\, dy=1+\frac{x-1}{e^{-x}} $$

Comment: Thanks, I think now I can solve it. Will edit it then.

Comment: I got $u(x)=xe^{x}$ as solution.

Comment: @math12 I think it is right :)

Comment: Anyway then the integral equation is fullfilled. Thank you!